# Delete file in linux server using curl command

Tags: java, curl, aem, crx

I want to delete a file I saved in the linux server using curl command. Basically trying to achieve "`rm -rf /myfolder/myFile.zip`" using curl.

I tried this command.  `curl -X DELETE /myfolder/myFile.zip`

But it throws an error : `curl: (3) <url> malformed`

I will ultimately need to run this via a java class, but for now, just trying to run it directly in linux to verify.

Am I missing some syntax here ? How can I provide a full url when I AM inside the very server ?

Comment: Why do you want to use curl?  Why even use a system command at all, when you have [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path))?

Comment: @VGR - Thanks. I just tried to go with curl because I downloaded my file to this location using curl, and now I wanted to delete it. Will give the files API a try for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is used for sending HTTP requests. Maybe you want to issue the `rm` command via ssh?

From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/160799/scp-files-and-delete-files-on-remote-directory) stackexchange question:

> ssh hostname "rm /myfolder/myFile.zip"

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one out